# Reading input from text file into an array in ruby

Tags: ruby, arrays, text-files

I want to read data from a text file and retrieve just the ip_addresses contained in the file.

The file contains data as:

```
[#<host:192.168.2.135>, #<host:175.41.142.49>, #<host:20:aa:4b:9b:eb:8c>, #<host:20:7c:8f:10:38:a0>, #<host:192.168.2.1>, #<host:239.255.255.250>]
```

From these data, i just want the host addresses like 192.168.2.135 and so on and store them in an array.Could somebody please help me with this?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

```
open(path_to_file, &:read).scan(/#<host:(.+?)>/).flatten
```

Comment: Now, if my file contains data like [#<sum 192.168.2.135 2411669>] and out of this, I want only the number 2411669, how should I do this?